# Make caption take width of image

Tags: html, css, image, width, figcaption

Consider the following example:

```
<figure>
  <img height="100px" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Test.png">
  <figcaption>Very long caption that should take the width of the image</figcaption>
</figure>
<div>This text should appear below the whole figure</div>
```

Is there a css-only approach that makes the caption take the width of the image that would work on the majority of browsers, so no please no bleeding edge css?

EDIT: A solution without intrinsic width (min-content).

EDIT: I added text below the figure that should also be below the caption.

Comment: I think you need to use javascript for this

Comment: What have you tried so far with css?

Comment: `width: min-content;` on the figure. Consider Browser support. https://caniuse.com/#search=width%3A%20min-content

Comment: @evayly without min-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Code**
https://jsfiddle.net/harshapache/sLeab4zg/

```
   figure {
      position: relative;
      display: table-caption;
   }
```

Comment: With this approach, text below the figure will overlap with the caption. I amended the example to show text below.

Comment: i have updated my solution, try this

Answer (score 0):

```
figure{
    display: table;
    width: 1px;
}
```